# Why GridSearchCV is cloning the estimator while fitting the data?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I don't understand why this is happening , and not just use the estimator in parameters?

```
base_estimator = clone(self.estimator)
```

How the estimator parameters are change during the search?
What function is call from the estimator?

Comment: What do you mean by a particular state of the estimators..

Comment: Most of the times, its the data that gives memory issues, and sklearn will use a single copy of data if possible on all clones. So show the code and describe the data to reach the underlying issue here.

Comment: @abunickabhi I don't understand why the estimator is clone basically and how it change the estimator parameters

Comment: @VivekKumar the estimator is a Deep Neural Network with a lot of layers so the clone operation copy this network and take lot of memory

Answer (score 1):

The problem you are facing seems to defined quite vaguely here, so first I will give out some background,

GridSearchCV implements a “fit” and a “score” method. It also implements “predict”, “predict_proba”, “decision_function”, “transform” and “inverse_transform” if they are implemented in the estimator used.

So , basically in scikit-learn , when you try and tune hyperparameters , you are always building an object which we can call the estimator.

Regarding , passing the arguments , the state of the estimators can be anything , when we try and pass the arguments which gives some constraints or bounds to the GridsearchCV function.

I hope I have addressed your confusion.

Comment: How grid search modify the estimator and why it close the estimator?

Comment: Grid search and cross validation are a combined process and they act on the data, maybe while the estimator is called , the program does not know whether to act on the new data or the previous data. Hence , it may be closing up whenever you run the code.